# How take lock for one entry?

Tags: mysql, sql

I moved out of global looking database to next sql query. I hope it works in next algorithm:
1) Select/take lock of 1 entry from table checkins.
2) Taking lock and update usage_flag, so i don't need worry about race condition.

```
            begin;
            SELECT GetDistance('newhaven', area) as distance, id = (SELECT @proxy_id := id) 
                from checkins
                WHERE last_checkin > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
                  AND active  = 1
                  AND offline = 0
                  AND usage_flag = 0
             ORDER BY distance ASC, RAND() limit 1 FOR UPDATE;
             UPDATE checkins set usage_flag=1 where id=@proxy_id;
             commit;
```

and but after one day in production, i see a ton errors :

```
'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction'
```

How can I improve this code, or maybe i totally wrong in my conjectures how `select for update` `begin-commit`and  works. Please correct me or time me some idea how do it better.

Comment: Your query will lock your whole table because you need all rows to calculate e.g. the order. I assume your query runs a longer time so you can just update directly without explicit locking? Is this code inside a procedure?

Comment: @Solarflare thank you for your answer. ``` Is this code inside a procedure?``` no, it is independent query. ```so you can just update directly without explicit locking``` i have a 300+ processes which use this query, and don't want use one entry in one time, so I definitely sure i need lock, but not whole table. Maybe you have some idea, how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Your query will basically lock the whole table, because it needs all rows to calculate the order.

I assume your query runs some time (otherwise you could just update in place), so your table is locked until it is finished calculating all distances. So either improve your distance calculation or don't lock it during that time.

To minimize lock time, you can seperate the (time-consuming) selection and the lock for update. If during selection the status has changed, you can just redo it outside the lock and try again.

You can e.g. use the following procedure

```
delimiter $$

create procedure SetUsageflag() 
begin
  set @LockCounter = 10;

  repeat 
    set @LockCounter = @LockCounter - 1;

    set @proxy_id = 
            (SELECT id from checkins
             WHERE last_checkin > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
                  AND active  = 1
                  AND offline = 0
                  AND usage_flag = 0
             ORDER BY GetDistance('newhaven', area) asc, RAND() 
             limit 1);

    start transaction;
    -- check if status is still 0, and lock that row 
    set @checkvalue = (select coalesce(usage_flag,0) 
                       from checkins where id = @proxy_id for update);
    if @checkvalue = 0 then
      update checkins set usage_flag = 1 where id = @proxy_id;
      set @LockCounter = 0;
      -- return result to caller
      SELECT GetDistance('newhaven', area) as distance, id 
      from checkins where id = @proxy_id;
    end if ;
    commit; 

    -- give up after some time
    if @LockCounter = 1 then 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Lock-Timeout trying to find an unused checkin!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1205; 
    end if;

  until (@LockCounter <= 1) end repeat;
end $$

delimiter ;
```

If it happens often that you have to redo the `select`, you might want to use a temporary table and add e.g. the 10 best entries and test them all one after another if the first ones fail, so you don't have to redo your calculation (I don't know how long it takes).

Answer (score 0):

But the way you have this structured you do need to lock the whole table
Select order limit 1 must lock the table as a change could change the output from the query

I suspect this is expensive

```
GetDistance('newhaven', area)
```

Can you store that output in a column

What do you really need?  You just need to know another process did not set usage_flag=1?

I don't know mysql but can you get a rowcount on this?

```
UPDATE checkins set usage_flag=1 where id=@proxy_id and usage_flag=0;
```

If another process already changed it to 1 then this would have rowcount of 0
This would avoid the (costly) transaction